# Ruby: 2 dimension arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

How do you declare a 2 dimension array in Ruby. I know, `V=[]` is one dimensional. But `v=[][]` for 2 dimensional? And in a block I want to add values as subarrays in a array. i.e. `V=[["ab","ba"]`,`["12","21"]]`. This is what I am doing. Let `x=[]`. I take each element, store the original as well as the reverse.

```
x.each{|k| l=k_reverse v=(k,l)}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# Given
list = ["ab","12"]
# This should give you an array of arrays
v = list.map{|x| [x,x.reverse] }
# v = [["ab","ba"],["12","21"]]
```

A 2 dimensional array could possibly be initialized as

```
v = [[]] # not [][], [][] would be the reader for a 2 dim array
```